# Static electric shock as I leave the car

Tags: electrical

Now this has started to "interfere with concentration". It is happening when i am getting out and trying to close the door. I feel a static shock as i touch the metal part of the door as my foot touches the ground.

I faced it in my last car as well, in that car the seat covers were of velvet cloth. But in this one they are plain (don't know the exact material). Do others face it as well and how do you avoid it?

Or does it has any relation to weather, I think it happens in cold days.

Comment: I do know that tire composition matters greatly in this conversation.  Certain tire brands can generate enough electrical charge to adversely affect radio reception on a new 1989 model.   I think they fixed the radios with some capacitor filter modifications.  With that said there really isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: new 89 model???

Comment: Holding a penny (or any other coin) and tapping it to the metal first will discharge without any pain. Larger, tighter contact area.

Comment: Be careful, there are legends that the spark can ignite fuel if the discharge happens when you are refueling.

Comment: @Juris - Ignition of non-compressed fuel requires direct flame, a spark is not enough

Comment: @Taegost You are correct. But can you ignite the vapor? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGVqwCVqCh8

Comment: I sometimes shut the door by pressing on the glass instead of the door frame to avoid static shocks

Comment: I eperience the same problem, except it happens on a Renault Espace! It happened on the last one, too. They both have fibreglass bodies!

Comment: @Taegost It is very hard to make petrol (liquid) burning. But it is very easy to make petrol fumes burning. And when you have good oxygen-to-fume ratio the spark is enough. When you have unfortunate combination of engine temperature, compression, air-to-fuel ratio your engine may suffer from self-igniting and if you fail to cool it down it may explode.

Comment: @Crowley - "Easy" and "hard" are relative terms, it all depends on the situation and factors involved.  Mythbusters proved that gas ignites between 500-540 degrees (source: http://mythresults.com/special7).  A spark by itself can't generate that kind of temperature.  I should have been a bit more clear in my statement

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the others face it as well. It depends on the pants and shoes you wear, as well as the material of your seats - static charge builds up between the different fabrics when you stand up because of the **triboelectric effect**. When you first touch a large metal body (such as the car frame), it immediately discharges, giving you the unpleasant sensation. Weather conditions matter as well, this phenomenon is more common in dry air conditions.

One trick you can try is to get out of the car *while* touching the metal frame of the car. This guarantees the charge will pass to the car before building up. This trick works in other situations when you get shocked by static as well: touching a metal table leg while standing up off a chair will prevent static discharge at home or office.

Comment: I just use my car keys to touch the door before I open or close it. Works like a charm.

Comment: The effect is worse with synthetics, I believe. For instance, when I wore poly-cotton hoodies in the winter, I'd generate enough charge that I'd get a shock from touching metal, such as a locker (or laptop!), but I don't commonly experience the same problem with cotton clothes.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced it as well, in some vehicles more than others. Typically, the days I get hit with it the most is, as you stated, on cold days. I don't think it's necessarily the cold day which does it, but rather the amount of humidity which is in the air. When the air is dry it tends to allow more static electricity buildup. The humidity is usually lower on colder days due to the fact there isn't as much evaporation going on around you to create the humidity.

On [this web page](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-static-electricity-occur-more-in-dry-than-humid-weather), they talk about this effect a little bit:

> These static charges build up normally by rubbing 2 materials together (an effect known as the [Triboelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) due to the friction of rubbing), for example while walking on carpet while wearing shoes (rubber soles vs carpet material). When the charge builds to a high enough level and you touch an electrically conductive part like a metal door handle, the static charge is suddenly released all at once and you notice the effect. At low enough levels, you do not actually perceive it even though it actually occurs.
>
> When it's humid, it's much easier (as you correctly mentioned) for the static charges that is being generated to dissipate before you touch a door handle. They dissipate away to the environment via the surrounding air & also back to the 'damp due to humidity' carpet.
>
> So when it's humid, less static charges build up to a level required to zap you and when it's dry you get zapped more.

Comment: Cold days are less humid as cold air physically cannot hold as much water in it as warm air.

Comment: Yes, it's more like DRY days. You get a lot of static shock in very dry and hot climates like Las Vegas, for example.

Comment: This is fairly common, in dry climates or seasons, as Chuck Le Butt mentions. I've seen aftermarket car products in Japan for this issue (high-meg conductive pads that are mounts to the car door with a wire to connect to a metal part behind the door panel) and these [link] (http://www.amazon.com/Cylinder-Anti-Static-Keychain-Electricity-Discharger/dp/B00880BCLA) must be for the same purpose.

Comment: It my be worth noting that on cold days most of us wear much more woven synthetic material (compare waterproof jacket and a fleece hoodie to, say, a plain cotton t-shirt) on these dry winter days, which multiplies the effect.

Answer (score 3):

One can add a strap that rubs on the road. It bleeds off static charge continuously. It is easy to install but has somewhat limited life. They do work, we have installed several over the years.

[image: Vehicle to ground strap]

Note also that it is important to bleed off the charge before removing the fuel cap. There are stories of fires being ignited by the spark.

Comment: I've seen this on old russian cars and nowhere else, which makes me a bit skeptical. Does it actually work? How?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing It's made of conducting rubber, that's all. You can try it by hanging a metal chain long enough to touch the road, but the chain is noisy and easier to snap.

Comment: @Agent_L Ah, conductive rubber. Makes sense, Always thought it was regular plain old rubber. Though is that enough to ground the vehicle? A conductive strip barely touching the asphalt?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Yes, all it takes to even out the static electricity is barely any conduction. After the initial shock it won't shock you again. That's because human body is also conducting enough. Just don't tie people to be dragged behind your car : )

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Conductive rubber consists of metal wires inside the rubber band. There wires are designed to conduct very low currents because static charges slowly. Look on fuel tank trailers or trolleybuses - these vehicles *must* be grounded - you shall find several rubber bands touching the ground. Fuel tanks must be grounded to prevent explosions, trolleybusses to prevent discharging through passengers.

Comment: @Crowley Never really noticed those. I thought fuel trailers are grounded when filling and emptying, not really much point in grounding them on the way.

Comment: These straps are unnecessary. Tires contain enough conductive materials (carbon, specifically added for this purpose) to provide a path to ground. You're getting shocked because you carry a static charge, not the car.

Comment: @Hobbes And yet for many people they solve the problem of static shocks when exiting the vehicle.  Why do you suppose the straps help so many people if they are unnecessary? Are you certain that every tire made today is sufficiently conductive to eliminate the chances of sparking by the time the person exits the vehicle?

Answer (score 1):

You could try spraying the upholstery with an anti-static spray, like what is used on the carpet in computer rooms and offices with computer equipment. Perhaps the spray used on clothing to prevent static cling would work also?

Answer (score 1):

> Or does it has any relation to weather, I think it happens in cold days.

There are two aspects that may make the effect larger on colder days. The main factor is that the air is dryer, so the charge the car develops as it moves through the air can be larger, and takes longer to discharge.  The second factor is that people usually wear warmer clothing, and often this type of clothing creates and retains a greater static charge that warmer weather clothing.

> Do others face it as well and how do you avoid it?

Yes, as long as the car is insulated from the ground then you will experience this.  What's happening is actually two discharges.  When you start to get out you are charged to the potential of the car.  Then your foot touches the ground and you discharge to the ground.  Then you touch the car door and you become the path for all of the car's charge to discharge to ground.  It's this second discharge that you feel - the first one happens through footwear and often is unnoticed, also your body doesn't carry as much charge as the vehicle, so the first discharge is relatively small.

A conductive strap hanging below the car works to eliminate this problem entirely.  When travelling quickly, the air pushes the strap up so it doesn't wear on the road all the time, but they do have to be replaced periodically. These disallow high charges to develop on the car, and don't themselves create sparks because the potential is simply never allowed to get that high.

I touch the door with the back of my hand or fingers after I get out, so the discharge occurs on the back of my hand or fingers.  This is much less sensitive than my fingertips where I'd usually contact the car to close the door.

In theory you can weld small needles to the metal frame of the car pointing toward the ground.  When the car is at a high potential, these will [emit electrons and discharge the potential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35614/is-lightning-attracted-to-pointy-objects) more quickly than the rounded, painted edges of the car. I don't know if this discharge would be fast enough to eliminate the shocks you feel, though, since you stop the car and immediately exit, but it should reduce them without the ground contact of a strap.  You'll need to choose a metal, alloy, or conductive covering that won't rust, or you'll be replacing them frequently.

If there's a part of the car you hold onto as you exit, attaching a wire from that part to the frame will also work.  So on my van I hold onto the door handle as I exit the vehicle.  It's plastic, though, so it doesn't conduct the vehicle's charge to me until I touch the outer edge of the door frame.  There are screws in the handle, so if I touched the screws, or attached copper tape along the inside edge of the handle to the screws then the discharge would happen at my feet as I left the vehicle, rather than between the door and my hand.

Lastly, you can get some plastic edge guards for the door frame.  If you install one and train yourself to only ever touch that as you close the door you should find the discharges go away.  If your trip away from the car was short, though, you'll get a shock as you touch the door handle or door when you return.

The conductive strap, however, is a cheap simple solution, available for [$10 including shipping](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057UNFDW) from some online stores, and can probably be found or ordered at your local auto parts stores. Hang it well under the vehicle where it won't be easily seen if you don't want well meaning people to constantly notify you that you've got something hanging under your car!

Comment: Those straps are unnecessary. Tires contain enough conductive materials (carbon, specifically added for this purpose) to provide a path to ground. You're getting shocked because you carry a static charge, not the car.

Comment: @Hobbes Regulations require a minimum amount of conductivity. However some low quality manufacturers are substituting silica for the carbon black which reduces conductivity, and some good manufacturers have reduced conductivity enough that they design in additional conductive rubber to comply with regulations.  If not installed well or correctly, though, even conductive tires may not provide sufficient grounding for the vehicle. http://articles.latimes.com/1994-07-29/news/ls-21275_1_tire-manufacturers ... http://moto.michelin.co.uk/advice/faq/about-the-design-and-composition-of-michelin-tyres

Comment: @Hobbes Also, note that if the "you are insulated from the car but have developed a charge" were true, then you'd get shocked when you touched the key to turn off the vehicle, and this would only happen if you had plastic keys or key covers. I'm still getting shocked from my big ford van with metal key and good quality name brand tires.

Comment: You get shocked when you get out of the car because the friction between you and the seat (as you move around to get out) builds a static charge on your body and the seat. The charge on the seat is quickly dissipated, which leaves a potential difference between your body and the car/ground.

Comment: @Hobbes So you're suggesting that the 2-4 four square feet of moving clothing against the car seat is sufficient to develop the static charge required for a 5-8mm spark, and that there is no other way people are experiencing sparks on modern cars? Given the reviews on amazon that suggest adding this strap resolved the sparking problem for most (but not all) I don't doubt that what you're saying is true for some, but not all. Creating that large a potential difference in the 1-2 seconds it takes to slide off the seat and touch the door seems less likely.

Comment: A car that doesn't dissipate static electricity would be a hazard. Sufficient conductivity between the ground and the car is a legal requirement. And yes, the action of moving out of your seat is sufficient to build up a nice big static charge.

Comment: @Hobbes Correct. I said as much up above, *"Regulations require a minimum amount of conductivity."* It feels like we are going to start going around in circles. Please consider adding your own answer to this question.

Comment: @AdamDavis Actually 2-4 square feet of moving clothing is more than sufficient. I find your theory about the car accumulating a charge being the reason for static discharge a bit hard to believe. The same phenomenon happens everywhere else when people get off chairs and touch the first large metal object they encounter (especially with synthetic clothing in dry air conditions), especially if the object is grounded. I encounter this myself every day. Also, your shoes should insulate you from the ground at least as well as the tyres of the vehicle, unless you drive bare footed.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing 1) yes that's sufficient area to generate a charge with the right materials. 2) if the car didn't generate charge then conductive tires wouldn't be required by regulation. 3) if my experience is incorrect and couldn't possibly happen, and your experience is the only possible answer, then there exists a small risk of generating a spark when fueling the vehicle once you touch the pump handle. At any rate, my answer doesn't preclude your answer, it's simply one possibility. Consider the people who find the static straps resolve the situation - how does that work?

Comment: @AdamDavis I never said the car can't accumulate any charge, I just doubt it is the reason for the phenomenon described by the OP. And discharging when fueling a vehicle is a very real risk, as already mentioned more than once if you read the rest of the answers and comments. It's a possibility, of course, I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm just not convinced and believe the other theory explains it better. Honestly I have no idea why or how the strap resolves the situation for those people and I'm not really taking 20 positive Amazon reviews as proof for this theory.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing *"I never said the car can't accumulate any charge, I just doubt it is the reason"* I expect, then, that you will find the following report entertaining, if not informative, regarding the collection of charge via vehicle movement, and how slowly that charge can dissipate: http://www.electrostatics.net/pdf/TB8%20Shocks%20in%20car%20parks.pdf I don't have access, but the paper *"Report on the Risk of Static Ignition During Vehicle Refuelling: A Study of the Available
Relevant Research."* by Smallwood JM. would likewise be relevant.

Comment: @AdamDavis Well, according to the report it's clearly possible, but apparently it only happens where the ground resistance is great, such as specifically designed parking areas. In such a case a grounding strap wouldn't do much, unfortunately. Getting out of the car still wouldn't ground you as well and it wouldn't be the car that shocked you. It is interesting, though.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing *"it only happens where the ground resistance is great"* That paper refers to "ground resistance" as the resistance between the frame of the car and ground, not the resistance of the ground itself.  This again points toward poorly conducting tires, which I discuss in my answer, and which a strap would solve.  Regardless, this comment thread is getting too long.  I'm sorry you find my answer unhelpful. I'm not interested in convincing people, but providing information that may help when answers like yours don't solve the problem.

Comment: @AdamDavis Yes, but the resistance between car and ground includes both tyre resistance and floor resistance, with the emphasis in this paper on the latter (poorly conducting floor surface). And if the floor resistance is very high, a strap won't save you from getting zapped.

Comment: Your answer isn't unhelpful, just debatable (which is what we are doing). The idea is definitely valid, but the part about body discharging what's accumulated while driving into the ground when getting out seems off and not really explained by the paper you mentioned. And even that one stands in very specific conditions, while this phenomenon happens all the time everywhere. And then the ground strap of questionable usefulness part.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing So essentially what you're saying, repeatedly, is, *"This isn't the most likely cause, though I accept it's possible."* and what I'm saying, repeatedly, is *"This is **a** possible cause, and **if** this is the case for the reader, then here's what you can do about it."* Yet you keep responding as though there's something important to debate here, and I don't see where we are disagreeing and why we are continuing to essentially repeat the same things over and over. If I'm misunderstanding your point, please clarify so I can improve my post.

Comment: @AdamDavis *sigh* no, that's not what I'm saying at all, you're cherry picking parts. And I really don't feel like continuing this anymore.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I'm sorry I'm misunderstanding your comments then. I've just re-read them and I still don't understand what your point is beyond *"I find your theory ... a bit hard to believe."* and *"I just doubt it is the reason for the phenomenon described"* which you repeated later *"It's a possibility, of course, I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm just not convinced and believe the other theory explains it better."* and again *"The idea is definitely valid, but the part about body discharging what's accumulated while driving into the ground when getting out seems off"*

Comment: @AdamDavis Your theory and the paper you provided explains different phenomenons, that's the main problem. I am agreeing with the fact that a car accumulated charge and can cause a discharge in very specific conditions and disagreeing with your theory that the passenger discharges the accumulated charge into the ground when getting out of the car while touching it. And the whole rubber strap thing as well, that one doesn't hold any water in either case.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing I understand your doubt, and see that I'm not going to be able to help you understand how electric charge is generated in a moving vehicle, how it's discharged, when and why that might not happen, and how a person touching the car and ground at the same time might be the discharge path. I work in the automotive industry as an electrical engineer and it's pretty straightforward for me.  All the references I have are not public, and I certainly can't say, "Just trust me" so I suppose I'll just have to accept that I cannot convince you. Sorry.

Comment: @AdamDavis No references are fine as long as you explain the mechanism. It's difficult to understand how you become charged to the vehicle's charge while getting out, why the first discharge happens through the shoes while the second one doesn't or why the shoes don't offer sufficient resistance to isolate you from the ground in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that happens a lot.  I hold my key with my fingers touching the metal, and tap the edge of the door after I turn.  I suspect that the turn-while-seated is when the static charge is generated.

Comment: charge is created when you slide on the seat to get out, movement creates the charge.

Answer (score 0):

I had this with a relatively modern car (2008 Honda Civic) a couple of years ago, and it was getting progressively worse. In the end I found that there was a small crack in the battery casing. When I replaced the battery the problem disappeared and never came back, so that might be worth investigating.

Comment: How would that work, from a physics standpoint?

Comment: Embarassingly, I have no idea. Maybe it wasn’t actually a problem with the battery but a problem with the earth (‘ground’ in US?) connection to the frame? Either way, it wasn’t static shock from clothing.

Answer (score 0):

After you open the door, but BEFORE you put your foot on the ground, grab a metal part of the car with your hand. Step out of the vehicle, and then release your hand.  Your body will still discharge the static electricity to ground, but because you are holding firmly to the car, there is no air gap for a spark to occur, and the larger surface area that you are touching with means that you won't feel the charge.